# "property description must have an object" error in react-native app. Why?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-0.57.1.

I'm getting an error :

```
"property description must have an object"
```

I have added a screenshot of the UI :

[image]

Can anyone help for this problem ?

Comment: can you explain a bit like when are you getting this error?

Comment: when i am running android, then this error is occurring.but in ios is fine

Comment: try cleaning gradle once.